# What is the value of s?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is something I came up with a day. I tried a procedure but later I found it was incorrect. So here it is:

$$2^s = 2s + 2 $$

Comment: This usually requires the use of [Lambert's W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Solving_equations); in particular, the example linked to is $3^x=2x+2$, almost exactly your equation.

Comment: Why do you expect this to have a clean solution?  Very quickly, mixing exponentials and polynomials you will enter the realm of "*[non-elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function#Non-elementary_functions)*" solutions.  This probably will only be solvable using things like Lambert-W functions or using numerical methods

Comment: (*In response to someone noting that $3$ is a simple solution to the equation*) 
 *A* simple solution, which can be spotted by inspection... It is implied that the OP is looking for an algebraic approach that doesn't rely on luck or a flash of inspiration to find the answer but a process.  It missed other solutions such as one near $-0.690093$ which you will not be so lucky as to write without using Lambert-W functions

Comment: There is no explicit solution for this equation.

Answer (score 1):

As the commentators have written,
the solution involves
the Lambert W-function.
Look it up.

The explicit solution
according to Wolfy
 is
$s = -\dfrac{W(-\log(2)/4) + \log(2)}{\log(2)}
$.

The numeric values
for the two branches 
of the W-function are
$s≈-0.690093
$
for the main branch and
$s = 3$
for the -1 branch.

Yep - 
$2^3 = 2\cdot 3 + 2$.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, that is a function I had no notion before. On my agenda to study it.

Comment: It's a fun one. $W(y)$ solves $xe^x = y$ for $x$.